# Regex patterns with log header

Tags: regex, perl

I want to compare the following string to my regex below. It doesnt seem to be working. Any suggestions?

String to compare : "User searched remoteexec.log for "player" @ 02:21:31"

This is my perl code.

```
my $qu_re = q{(.?) searched (.?) for "(.?)" @ (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)};
```

Comment: You should use `qr` for quote regex. What's your question too?

Comment: What parts are you wanting to match/capture?

Comment: @squiguy - My question is how would I compare the regex to the string.

Comment: @Jason Gray -  The whole string.

Answer (score 3):

You are lacking some quantifiers, `+`:

```
my $qu_re = q{(.+?) searched (.+?) for "(.+?)" @ (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)};
                ^              ^          ^
```

Otherwise, they would match 0 or 1 character only. This should suit you, but I would rather use something more restrictive if you ask me though:

```
my $qu_re = q{(\w+) searched (\w+\.log) for "(\w+)" @ (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})};
```

Here though, I'm assuming that `User`, `player` and `remoteexec` can be alphanumeric and contain underscores. `{2}` near to `\d` means there are only 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = qq{User searched remoteexec.log for "player" @ 02:21:31};
my $qu_re = qr{(.+) searched (.+) for "([^"]+)" @ (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)};

if( $str =~ m/$qu_re/ ) {
    print "user: ", $1, "\n";
    print "what: ", $2, "\n";
    print "player: ", $3, "\n";
    print "when: ", "$4:$5:$6" , "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
user: User
what: remoteexec.log
player: player
when: 02:21:31
```